# Is there a way to add line breaks ONLY when exporting to PDF in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I think the question is quite self-explanatory but for avoidance of doubt I'll explain with more detail below:

I have an R Markdown document that works well if converted to HTML or uploaded to GitHub. When converting to PDF (using Latex), the results are not so pretty. I find that the biggest problem in a Latex PDF document are line breaks. I can fix the line breaks issue on the PDF document by adding "\  " characters, but that throws my HTML document out of whack too.

Is there a way to manually add line breaks (or "space before/after paragraphs") for the PDF output only?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe you want `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` or , perhaps better,`\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}`... Using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211638/89990) to add it to the latex preamble

Comment: I think the first line is very useful! How can I add space before code blocks too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the relevant spacings in the YAML header.  `\parskip` controls the paragraph spacing.  Code blocks are shaded using a `snugshade` environment from the `framed` package.  We can also redefine the shaded environment for code blocks to have some vertical space at the start.  Here's a reproducible example. Note: I also added the `keep_tex` parameter so you can see exactly what the generated tex file looks like, in case this is useful:

---

````
title: "test"
author: "A.N. Other"
header-includes:
   - \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
   - \renewenvironment{Shaded}{\vspace{\parskip}\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Answer (score 1):

Once you output to HTML, you can just print the HTML webpage as PDF. that might be an easy way keep the original format